# Pass HTTP request from Azure Function through Event Grid

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I've started thinking through a prototype architecture for a system I want to build based on Azure Functions and Event Grid.

What I would like to achieve is to have a single point of entry (Function) which a variety of external vendors will send Webhook (GET) HTTP requests to. The purpose of the Function is to add some metadata to the payload, and publish the package (metadata + original payload from vendor) to an Event Grid. The Event Grid will then trigger another Function, whose purpose is to respond to the original Webhook HTTP request with e.g. a status 204 HTTP code.

The diagram below is a simplified version of the architecture, the Event Grid will of course publish events also to other Functions, but for the sake of simplicity…

The challenge I'm facing at the moment is that the context of the original Webhook HTTP request from external vendor is lost after the first Function is triggered. Trying to send the context as part of the event payload to Event Grid feels like an anti-pattern, and regardless I cannot get it working (the `.done()` function is lost somewhere in the event). Trying to just use `context.res = {}` and `context.done()` in the last Function won't respond to the vendor's original HTTP request.

Any ideas here? Is the whole architecture just one big anti-pattern -- will it even work? Or do I have to immediately send the HTTP response in the first Function triggered by the vendor's request?

Thank you!
[image: Minimal illustration of architecture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two difference patterns such as a message-driven and event-driven. 
The Azure Event Grid is a distributed Pub/Sub eventing Push model, where the subscriber subscribing an interest on the source in the loosely decoupled manner.

In your scenario, you want to use an eventing model within the message exchange request-response pattern in the sync manner. The request message exchange context can not flow via the Pub/Sub eventing model and back to the anonymous endpoint such as actually a point for response message.

However, there are a several options how to "logical" integrate these two different patterns, the following is showing some of them:

1. using a **request - replyTo** message exchange pattern, such as a full duplex communication, one for request and the other one for replyTo.
2. using a **request - response** message exchange pattern with a **polling state**. Basically, your first function will wait for a subscriber state and then return back to the caller. In the distributed internet architecture, we can use an azure lease blob storage for sharing a state between the sync part and async eventing part.
   In your scenario, the first AF will create this lease blob, then firing an event to the AEG and then it will periodically polling the state in the lease blob for end of aggregation process (multiple subscribers, etc.).

   Also, for this kind of pattern, you can use [Azure Durable Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview) to simplify an integration to the event-driven AEG model.

The following screen snippet shows a sequence diagram using an Azure Lease Blob for sharing a "Request State" in the distributed model. Note, that this pseudo sync/async pattern is suitable for cases when the Request-Response is processing within a short time less than 60 seconds.

[image]

For more details about using a Lease Blob within the Azure Function, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481832/azure-blob-storage-acquireleaseasync-synchronously-wait-until-lock-is-release).

Comment: Roman, thank you very much for your detailed explanations! Durable Functions will definitely help in the development of the architecture, so thank you for the link.