# how to move multiple blobs in one transaction?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

**How can we move multiple blobs in one transaction?**

I'm currently moving 1 blob at a time like so:

```
    public static async Task MoveBlobInSameStorageAccount(string name, string from, string to, string connection)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connection, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(from);
        var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
        var destinationContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(to);
        var destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
        await destinationBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob);
        await sourceBlob.DeleteAsync();
    }
```

However, I need to be able to move 5 - 10 blobs at a time.

**How do we move multiple blobs in one transaction from a source container to a destination container?**

Comment: You mean copy a container or just pick up some blobs in a container to move?

Comment: i'd like to pass in a list of uri's pointing to specific blobs, and the function should copy all of those blobs within the same context/connection/transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library). I recently used it on a project, worked well.

Specifically, you want to use:

> CopyDirectoryAsync

There is a samples folder in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) that you can reference. I didn't need most of the code in the samples, so I modified:

> BlobDirectoryCopySample

I also used the [Utils](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Util.cs) class in the sample folder. You can set ParallelOperations as well, which "gets or sets a value indicating how many work items to process concurrently".

```
namespace DataMovementSamples
{
    using System;
#if !DOTNET5_4
#endif
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;

    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Data movement directory copy sample.");
                await BlobDirectoryCopySample();
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Cleanup generated data.");
            }
        }

        private static async Task BlobDirectoryCopySample()
        {
            var sourceBlobDir = await Util.GetCloudBlobDirectoryAsync("sourcecontainer", "dir1");
            var destBlobDir = await Util.GetCloudBlobDirectoryAsync("targetcontainer", "dir2");

            var options = new CopyDirectoryOptions()
            {
                Recursive = true,
            };

            var context = new DirectoryTransferContext();
            context.FileTransferred += FileTransferredCallback;
            context.FileFailed += FileFailedCallback;
            context.FileSkipped += FileSkippedCallback;

            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 50;
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer started");

            try
            {
                Task task = TransferManager.CopyDirectoryAsync(sourceBlobDir, destBlobDir, false, options, context);
                await task;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The transfer is cancelled: {0}", e.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The transfer is completed.");
        }

        private static void FileTransferredCallback(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer Succeeds. {0} -> {1}.", e.Source, e.Destination);
        }

        private static void FileFailedCallback(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer fails. {0} -> {1}. Error message:{2}", e.Source, e.Destination, e.Exception.Message);
        }

        private static void FileSkippedCallback(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer skips. {0} -> {1}.", e.Source, e.Destination);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much this is really nice. id like to be able to pass 3 different blobs to my function, and the result would be that they would all be uploaded within the same "stream" or whatever you would call it

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, CopyDirectoryAsync is the only way to move a group of blobs in one transaction. You can use CopyAsync, but that would still process one at a time, which does not satisfy your requirement.

Comment: thanks again! on a tangent ... im concerned about race conditions, suppose i have 2 separate processes that move files away from the same container ... how do i ensure they dont step on each other?

Comment: I had similar concerns and ended up using one process to handle this. I do not think TransferManager.CopyDirectoryAsync is thread-safe. You will have to manage that yourself. Should be easy enough with lock.

Comment: Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: `lock` would be relevant if i were attempting to do this from the same function, but i will have multiple instances of the same function opening separate connections against the same blob, so `lock` wouldnt be relevant here

Comment: Yes correct, I misread your comment and too quick to respond to your comment. You will have to use a mutex. A mutex is used to ensure exclusive access to a shared resource across processes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', in the distributed serverless architecture we can use an azure storage **Lease Blob** for handling a exclusive access across all instances. Each instance have to *AcquireLeaseAsync* to obtain an exclusively ownership for temporary time, see my answer for this implementation in the Azure Function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481832/azure-blob-storage-acquireleaseasync-synchronously-wait-until-lock-is-release