# Trigger Azure Function when two events occur | Merge events in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I know that there is EventGrid trigger for Azure Functions and I successfully used it in the past.
What I need now is to trigger another Azure Function only after TWO different events occurred (the order of events might be different).

In other words what I need is:

```
Event A occurred -> After some time Event B occurred -> Immediately execute Azure Function X
```

or

```
Event B occurred -> After some time Event A occurred -> Immediately execute Azure Function X
```

Is there an Azure Services that allows to merge or combine events from two different sources and convert it to one event? Or should I somehow persist the information what events occurred? Any suggestions?

Comment: have a look at the Pattern #6 - Aggregator of the Durable Function, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#aggregator

Comment: for simple solution with a little coding can be used a **lease blob** for storing a state of the events. See more details how to use a lease blob in the azure function in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481832/azure-blob-storage-acquireleaseasync-synchronously-wait-until-lock-is-release

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved via various services. Eg

### Azure Logic Apps

You can execute your workflow based on conditions. [More Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement)

#### Using Service Bus

Consider a message is an event, based on the type of property inside the message you can determine what to do with your event.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for aggregation pattern of the events with a generic and flexible solution (more events, etc.) is to ingest the AEG events to the *stream pipeline* (Event Hub event handler) and using the **Azure Stream Analytics job** for generating an event interest for outputting to the Azure Function.

The following screen snippet shows this full declarative solution:

[image]