# Is there a way to wait for a set of Azure Functions? Currently using Service Bus

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to generate a number of Word reports in parallel using Azure Functions (.net isolated 5). I'd like to be able to detect when a set of Azure Functions have completed - so I can then combine them all into a zip file and send that to the user.

The way I'm doing it at the moment is with a Service Bus queue that has Sessions enabled. However, this means that the items in the queue will be processed in sequence, rather than in parallel.

It looks like partitioning might help - i.e. a set of messages **will** be processed in parallel. But then is there a way to sequence the zip step after the partition completes?

Comment: could you please state the version of .net isolated 5 or 6 you're using>

Comment: for *FanOut-FanIn* patterns can be used a **lease blob** to figure out which worker (function) in the FanOut process is last one. See my answer in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481832/azure-blob-storage-acquireleaseasync-synchronously-wait-until-lock-is-release

Comment: I should mentioned what version of .net it was! I haven't looked into it, but assuming I could use a .net 5 library with the .net 6 runtime, I'd be happy to upgrade

Comment: Did you upgraded to the newer version or found any workaround to your issue?

Comment: I'll be working on this in the new year. I'll probably look into the Fan Out/In pattern (mentioned above). But I may end up testing .net 6 too

Comment: After some thought and experiment, I've decided to upgrade to .net 6 (without .net isolation) so I can use Durable Functions. Which means I'll probably have to rewrite the code for .net isolated when 7 comes out!

Comment: Oh, and you can refer to a .net 5 assembly from .net 6