# Azure function instances and synchronization

Tags: multithreading, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function implemented using C#.

The code support 3 different actions that the user can choose from by setting a field in the request to the function.

My code currently have 3 methods which all use a shared boolean flag which was written with the thought that only a new function's instance runs every time:

```
public class MyMainClass
{

 public bool flag = true;

 public int Method1()
 {
     while(flag)
     {
        ... somewhere here change the flag to false
     }
 }
 
 public int Method2()
 {
     while(flag)
     {
        ... somewhere here change the flag to false
     }
 }
}
```

My question is if when using an Azure function, do I need to take care of protecting the `flag` variable when several requests arrive at the same time and one request may cause an unwanted change in the flag for another? Or a new instance is created for each call and then there's no such danger?

Comment: you should consider a **lease blob with a shareable resource** to synchronize a workflow in the serverless architecture, see more about that in my answer in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481832/azure-blob-storage-acquireleaseasync-synchronously-wait-until-lock-is-release

Answer (score 0):

There is excellent [guidelines regarding parallel invocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#parallel-execution):

> Each instance of the function app, whether the app runs on the Consumption hosting plan or a regular App Service hosting plan, might process concurrent function invocations in parallel using multiple thread.

So, regarding your question:

> My question is if when using an Azure function, do I need to take care of protecting the flag variable when several requests arrive at the same time and one request may cause an unwanted change in the flag for another?

I'd say yes, you have to make sure your logic is thread safe. Also do mind that  multiple function instances may be involved so different instances may have different values of `flag`.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to ensure that each call will invoke a new instance so that each have a different flag of its own?

Comment: You code does not show how the `flag` is influenced per request, can you post that? Also, how is `MyMainClass` instantiated?

Comment: Like I said that it's a part of an Azure Function so it's being instantiated however an Azure function does it which I have no idea how... And you can see in the sample code that the flag influence the work of the function - when its true it will keep looping and working and when it's false, the method ends