# Caching or temporarily holding an object in Azure function Apps to cross check the status in every execution

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-functions, azureservicebus, software-design

I am developing an Azure Function App in C# which is designed to control the execution of a few other micro services.
[image]

So there is a configuration the controller function uses which decides which microservice to run. It looks like this

```
{
    "executionSequence": [
        {
            "sequence": 1,
            "service": "service1endpoint"
        },
        {
            "sequence": 2,
            "service": "service3endpoint"
        },
        {
            "sequence": 3,
            "service": "service3endpoint"
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on this configuration the controller decides what sequence the services needs to run.
When each services finishes its operation, it posts a message to the service bus saying its finished its part.

```
{
    "serviceName":"service1",
    "status":"completed"
}
```

It triggers the queue trigger function of the controller which the execute the next item in the sequence.

Those are working fine according to design. But my confusion is there are situation service1 and service2 needs to run in parallel. And when both completed only service 3 needs to fire.

So in that case the sequence will be 1 for service 1 and 2. So controller will fire 1 and 2 together.

So if service 1 finishes first it will post the the message into queue and trigger the controller. But for triggering service 3, it needs service 2 also should complete.

How we can handle that situation. or is there is any way other than DB, to mark 1 is completed and needs 2 also to be completed and then to fire service 3

Please share your thoughts

**Redis Cache is not enabled for us

Comment: Do you know durable functions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp

Comment: @MarkusMeyer We thought about that. But if we rely on messaging, it works more like a decoupled/independent architecture or doesn't need to loop until the second function is finished.

Comment: @SandeepThomas, another way (technique)  for storing the sequences of your state machine in the serverless event driven distributed architecture is using a **lease blob**, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481832/azure-blob-storage-acquireleaseasync-synchronously-wait-until-lock-is-release