Blob storage events for multiple files upload operation
I have a process that uploads multiple files to azure blob storage.
That storage raises events (either through storage trigger or event grid).
I need to be able to determine from events consumer perspective when the last file has been uploaded by the previous process because event consumer can start its part only when all files are uploaded.
How to achieve that?
I was thinking using custom metadata property on each file/blob like islastfileinbatch and make consumer react to that but not sure if there is some better option?

What mechanisms do you have for notifying the consumer? Could do with a few more details, but one idea might be a Durable Function Orchestration which would fan-out to multiple Activities (one for each upload) and then fan-in again, and notify the client with a SignalR or similar once completed. If you give some more background, I can try to suggest an answer around that.

@AndrewB the consumer is not end user (or browser). The consumer in this context is another background process on the server that gets EventGrid events that were raised as each blob is being uploaded to blob storage.

I think you could follow the same principle I suggested then, but have the final step in the Durable Function being to raise another EventGrid message notifying of completion?

@AndrewB I would like to avoid orchestration if possible. The whole system is done in choreography pattern and I would like to keep it that way.

I came up with a solution where the process that puts multiple files into blob storage would also be responsible to upload summary file at the end of its procedure.
Summary file would contain references to all files in a batch.
My consumer would then react to the event related to summary file.

In the distributed event driven serverless architecture, the state can be stored in the leased blob, where the pre-processor will create this state and each FAN-IN processor will update it in the concurrently manner. The last one will generate an event for post-processor. Example how to handle/access a leased blob in the serverless architecture can be found in the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481832/azure-blob-storage-acquireleaseasync-synchronously-wait-until-lock-is-release

@RomanKiss I can sure understand this pattern when different processors need to sync. In my case, its always one processor that drops several files into blob. In that scenario, do you see any downside going with summary file?

Sending a summary file with details of the uploaded files as an event to start a post-processing is fine, but the sender of this file must be sure that all files in the batch have been uploaded, and they are accessible. Note, that this information doesn't have a main process, the files are uploaded asynchronously, and their order is not guaranteed. Note, that the storage event subscriber has this direct information, so the solution needs some the FAN-IN process to figure out the last uploaded file is done. ...

Another option to figure out that all files have been uploaded (into the same container) is using an index tag (let's calling the Batch ID). The main process will query this storage for this index tag (BatchID) after what the last file has been uploaded. Based on that, the main program can send a summary file (actually a result of this query) to trigger a post-processing phase.

@RomanKiss maybe I am missing something but it is the same process that uploads all files so it does have info when all files have been uploaded.

It is depended how the process of uploading files is designed. In the case of uploading one by one with waiting for finishing each async/sync uploaded file, then you have this info, but this scenario is suitable for few and small uploading files.

@RomanKiss I have read your link and also your text linked from that post. I am not clear about one thing - who decides that the Nth file uploaded is the last one? Is that the post-processor?

No, it is not the post-processor, but any of the processors (making a particular job), which run concurrently with the dynamic processing with a possibility nesting, etc. has the capability to generate a transition event to the next state, for instance, starting a post-processor (FAN-IN). The state of this distributed state machine is holden in the leased blob, so during its updating, the processor knows that its job is the last one. The model of the distributed state machine can be a part of the logical model of the metadata driven architecture and it can be very simple-onedimensional or 3D.

@RomanKiss so a pre-processor would write total number of jobs it fans out to into the leased blob?

That's correct, the pre-processor (FAN-OUT) will create it (or is done by the design time from the logical model as a metadata), also retrying policy, timestamps, watchdog to finish a job/task, recovering policy, etc. The state machine stored in the leased blob gives you a runtime details about your processing for monitoring, troubleshooting and simulation/emulation and of course also for user control such as a request to pause, cancel, resume, etc.

@RomanKiss ok, that makes total sense. Thank you for clarification! Maybe you could formulate  your comments into an answer with these details and I will accept it because it is more general answer than the one I proposed.
